# Capturing Cmd output in log files - Error

Tags: c#, cmd, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have an issue in executing the following command in my production environment.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\putty\PLINK.EXE" -ssh user@server -pw password batch "cmd" 1> logfile 2>&1
```

However the same command executes fine in my other servers and creates the log file.

The command is executed in a c# script with in ssis and as a sql server agent job.

I did not get an error while execution but i dont see the log files either. 
I believe this is an environment issue. At this point i still do not have access to the prod server for debugging.

Kindly share your thoughts.
Thanks in advance,
Kannan

Comment: Does SQL Agent Job account (either SQL Agent or proxy) have sufficient rights to create a logfile? And in which directory it is to be created?

Comment: what about adding this as a Execute Process Task to see what error you are getting if any?  you can log errors from your script to Agent Logs that is probably more cumbersome but something good in the long run.  Likely account privileges to create logfile, directory, or even accessing plink.exe.